# Como cambiar FormBorderStyle en tiempo de ejecucion en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Tengo un form que dependiendo de si un string esta vacio o no cambie el FormBorderStyle de None a FixedDialog, pero al tratar de utilizar la propiedad en el codigo me marca el error:

"Se requiere una referencia de objeto para el campo, metodo o propiedad 'Form.FormBorderStyle' no estaticos"

cabe mencionar que no tengo ninguna clase estatica en uso , dejo la fraccion de codigo de lo que estoy intentando

```
private void NuevaVenta_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_idbusqueda)
        {
            NuevaVenta.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        }}
```

anexo una captura del error que me manda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te fijas, Visual Studio te esta pintando la palabra NuevaVenta en color verde oscuro, estas haciendo referencia al nombre de la clase y no al objeto instanciado, en todo caso si quieres cambiar el FormBorderStyle de NuevaVenta -> el códio que estas escribiendo actualmente ya se encuentra en esa clase, entonces tienes que hacer referencia al objeto actual que sería:

> **this.FormBorderStyle**

El código te quedaría así:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_idbusqueda))
{
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
}
```

o si lo prefieres puedes poner solamente FormBorderStyle, yo pondría this.FormBorderStyle solo para cerciorarme a que objeto le cambio la propiedad y a la hora de leer el código resulta mas intuitivo.

Un saludo.